# Download from BitBucket - Authorization failed

Tags: ubuntu, bitbucket

I would like to download an older version of my project from bitbucket to my ubuntu server.

I am typing the following command

```
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/owner/projectname/get/versionId.tar.gz
```

but I am getting the message

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED - Authentication failed
```

What else should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `wget --user=username --ask-password url` to authenticate.

Don't use the --password option because that will leave your password in plain text in the history.

You can avoid having to enter the username and password by adding

```
user=username
password=password
```

to ~/.wgetrc or /etc/wgetrc.

*(I recognize this is almost the same answer as Chris gave, but feel the security issue with --password is big enough to warrant it, and adding that and the wgetrc bit as a comment would be a bit much and be hidden behind a more comments link at the bottom.)*

Answer (score 4):

If your project is private, you'll need to authenticate.

The `--user` and `--password` options to `wget` are normally used for HTTP and FTP authentication, and can be used to download private releases from BitBucket:

```
wget --user=username --password=password
    https://bitbucket.org/owner/projectname/get/versionId.tar.gz
```

If your user or password includes characters that your shell might treat specially like `&`, `!`, `"` or `'` you'll need to wrap the argument in quotes. For example, a password of `salt&pepper` would have to be used like `... --password='salt&pepper' ...`.

From `man wget`:

```
--user=user
--password=password
    Specify the username user and password password for both FTP and
    HTTP file retrieval.  These parameters can be overridden using the
    --ftp-user and --ftp-password options for FTP connections and the
    --http-user and --http-password options for HTTP connections.
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, i got a "Scheme missing" message

Comment: @user2008973, ah, did you maybe type the backslash I included to show that the command should go on one line? I'll remove that since it may be confusing.

Comment: Again, I have an authorization failed message. I am wondering whether the proper credentials are the ones I am using to connect to bitbucket or not. I am sorry for the 'naive' questions, I am not that used to working with linux, git and bitbucket.

Comment: @user2008973, the credentials to use should be the ones you use to log into the BitBucket website. Test them there.

Comment: I typed the following command: sudo wget --http-user=myusername http-password='mypasswordwithspecialcharacters' https://bitbucket.org/owner/projectname/get/versionId.tar.gz but still authentication fails. I do not know what else to check. Anyhow, thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: @user2008973, is your *`sudo` authentication* perhaps failing, or are you still getting the HTTP 401 message? When you `sudo` a command you must input your user's local computer password.

Comment: yes I have already provided the sudo password correctly . I am receiving 401 message.